# WPML String translation for Custom theme not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wpml

I am developing a custom wordpress theme and the client requirement is that the site should be on two languages (i.e English and Chinese).

I am facing using translating theme options. I have installed all the plugins required like CMS, String translation and Translation Management but yet the translation is not working.

I have created the XML file as well and stored it on the theme root folder.

After all, this the error is displayed as:

[theme_switched: 0] shineway_footer_partnertwo: http://yelkolab.com/projects/shineway/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/e.png
string not registered

I have using following code snippet to display theme option values on site:

```
<?php echo stripslashes(get_option('shineway_footer_partnertwo'));?>
```

Comment: Make sure you add your code snippet -- as it stands, we can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `_e` instead of `echo`:

```
<?php _e( stripslashes(get_option('shineway_footer_partnertwo')), 'your-text-domain' ); ?>
```

Afterwards rescan your theme with String Translation and add the translation.

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either... Still the problem exists